# strcmp() unsigned char to string within a file

Tags: c, arrays, hash, file-io, strcmp

I need a method by which the output of this hash function can be compared to a string that resides within a separate file, however the output is usually defined as `printf("%02x", c[i]);` (where the comment is). This format does not work for comparisons sake, and I'm unsure of how to adjust this format essentially.

```
            FILE *ftest=fopen(hashInBuf, "rb");
            SHA512_Init (&mdContext);
            while ((bytes = fread (data, 1, 1024, ftest)) != 0)
                SHA512_Update (&mdContext, data, bytes);
            SHA512_Final (c,&mdContext);
            if(access(hashOutBuf, F_OK) != -1){
               for(i = 0; i < SHA512_DIGEST_LENGTH; i++){
                 //METHOD TO COMPARE WITH TO EXISTING HASH FILE (stored in seperate folder)
               }
            }
```

The string in the file is the output of this hash function (stored by using `fprintf(*file, "%02x", c[i]);`) - this residing where the comment is above. Thank you in advance.

Comment: I'm not sure I understand the problem. What variables are you trying to compare? Can't you use `sscanf("%2x")` to parse the hex value, then compare the numbers? Or `sprintf("%02x")` to convert the number to a string and then use `strcmp()`?

Answer (score 2):

Convert each pair of characters of the external string to an integer.

```
const char *external_string = "2435CD76F...";
for(i = 0; i < SHA512_DIGEST_LENGTH; i++) {
  //         v------------------------------------------------v Compound literal (C99) 
  if (strtol((char [3]){external_string[0], external_string[1]}, 0, 16) != data[i]) {
    return Different;
  }
  external_string += 2;
}
return Same;
```

Insure `data` is  `unsigned char` or use `.... != (unsigned char) data[i]`